# How to Get Posts From all the people i Follow?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using Postgresql to store my data.
This the table where i store all the tweets made by any user. Tweets are stored in in a json Array.

```
CREATE TABLE tweets (
    tweet_user_id UUID NOT NULL,
    user_tweets jsonb[]
);
```

In this table i store all followers and following of a user.

```
CREATE TABLE friends_details(
    user_id UUID,
    followers UUID[] DEFAULT '{}',
    following UUID[] DEFAULT '{}'
);
```

The query i am using to get all the posts from the people i follow is:-

```
SELECT user_tweets F
FROM tweets 
WHERE tweet_user_id IN (SELECT following FROM friends_details 
                        WHERE user_id = '$1' , [user_uid]);
```

But i am getting this error:-

> operator does not exist: uuid = uuid[]

How do i solve this error and get all the posts from people i follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare a scalare and an array with `=`. Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tweets.user_tweets F
FROM tweets
   JOIN friends_details ON tweets.tweet_user_id = ANY (friends_details.following)
WHERE friends_details.user_id = $1;
```

Answer (score 0):

in stead of IN you should use = ANY(following)

Your query should look like this.

```
SELECT user_tweets F
FROM friends_details
  JOIN tweets ON tweets.tweet_user_id = ANY(friends_details.following)
WHERE friends_details.user_id = $1;
```

Notice, I've changed the form of the query to use join in stead of subquery. This is because in PostgreSQL [ANY(array)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) and [ANY(subquery)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME) acts differently. The former compares left side of equation to all the elements in the array, the latter compares it to all the rows in subquery, so using ANY(subquery) would result in error:
`SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = uuid[]`

You could use UNNEST to keep the SQL as similar to the one you currently use as possible:

```
SELECT user_tweets F
FROM tweets 
WHERE tweet_user_id IN (SELECT UNNEST(following) FROM friends_details 
                        WHERE user_id = $1);
```